# Can someone help me understand Cramer's Rule?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm taking notes for my class and they define cramers rule and afterwards give us an example problem.

\begin{align*}
x_1 + 2\,x_2 =& 2\\
-x_1 + 4\,x_2 =& 1
\end{align*}

They compute 
$$\det(a_1(b)) = \begin{vmatrix}2&2\\ 1&4\end{vmatrix}$$ 
and then they compute 
$$\det (a_2(b)) = \begin{vmatrix}1&2\\-1&1\end{vmatrix}\text{.}$$

I was wondering why for the first determinant the column 2,1 is before; however, for the second determinant the column 2,1 is after. Shouldn't the column 2,1 be the second column for both determinants.

Comment: I have no idea how to make matrices on this website... for det (a1(b)) the first column is 2,1 and then the second column is 2,4. For the second determinant the first column is 1,-1 and the second column is 2,1

Comment: Now you have it put in a nicer format.

Comment: use this $ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
g & h  \end{array} \right)$

Answer (score 0):

No, the matrices are correct.

For Cramer's rule, you replace the column corresponding to the variable with the column of numbers on the other side of the equals sign. As Amzoti pointed out, to get to the final answer, you divide both $\det(a_1)$ and $\det(a_2)$ by the same determinant of the matrix of the coefficients (with no replacement).

Comment: Okay, I'm doing a homework problem now with cramer's rule but this problem has three linear equations. So, then I'm going to have to solve for det(a3(b)). Where would the b be?